# Python want to increment one array element, and it increments all of the array elements at the same column

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have a two dimensional array.

```
teamStats = [[0] * 3] * 13
```

when i want to do this:

```
teamStats[0][0] = teamStats[0][0] + 1
```

the whole subarrays first element increments such like if i did with `teamStats[:][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the team stats this way in order to have different lists inside a list:

```
teamStats = [[0,0,0] for i in range(13)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
[0]*3
```

creates three references to one array, so manipulating one reference manipulates the one array.

Try

```
teamStats = [[0 for j in range(3)] for j in range(13)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
teamStats = [[0] * 3 for i in range(13)]
```

By doing

```
teamStats = [[0] * 3] * 13)]
```

you create 13 pointers to the same object [0,0,0] so when you try change one of them, at the same time you change all of them.

Comment: This suffers from the same reference problem for [0]*3

Comment: Try it. 0 is a constant so it cannot be referenced as a variable (object) with a pointer because it cannot be changed.

Comment: [0] is not a constant, it’s an array.

Comment: Why? I posted the corect answer ;-)

Comment: Because it does the same thing but with really better time complexity.
try,
>>>  a = [0 for _ in range(100000000)]
>>> a = [0]*100000000
and check the time it took each one. Then try to change an element to see if it  works as it should.